# Understanding Hibernate query

Tags: jpa

I'm new to Hibernate and I encountered a query today:

```
select new SomeClassDTO(r.id, r.name, r.description, u.id) from ClassA as u 
inner join u.data as r where u.email !=?1 and r.name not like '%Blah%
```

Can you please explain how this query works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query takes several fields from a `ClassA` entity with it's associated `data` Entity(s) and passes those field values into the constructor for class `SomeClassDTO`.

As the name of the created object implies, this is a way to take data from multiple associated database-mapped Entities, and construct a Data Transfer Object (DTO) to pass to your presentation layer.

You are essentially creating a 'view' of your database Entities and constructing new objects to hold the records of the result set of that view.